# Orchard CMS one widget for few layers

Tags: orchardcms

I have advanced menu widget and two layers for home page and ordinary content page. Is it possible to place one widget to two layers, or what is a right way to reuse widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible, you will need a copy of the widget in each layer, or you'll need to define a layer that uses a rule that is an "or" combination of the rules for each layer.

Comment: Can Orchard layers be multiplied? This can be soluton to create layer for common widgets. My task is to place search widget for all layers.

Comment: As I told you, create a layer with a rule that is an "or" combination of the rules of the layers you want to combine. But if you want the widget to appear on *all* pages, it's even easier, just use the default layer (its rule is "true")